# Apache Rewritemap Loop

Tags: php, regex, apache, url-rewriting

I have the following problem. I use a rewritemap written in php to rewrite my urls.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.(js|css|less|png|php|swf|flv|jpg))$
RewriteRule ^ /${redirect:$1} [L]
```

redirectmap looks like

```
$stdin = fopen("php://stdin","r");
$uri = trim(fgets($stdin));
$result = processUri($uri);
print "$result\n";
fclose($stdin);
```

When I enter the url example.com/foobar it should be rewritten to example.com/search.php?what=foobar

Overall it's working but sometimes... or after the first rewrite was successfully when I enter example.com/foobar its rewritten to example.com/foobar/index.html/index.html/index.html etc

Can anyone help?

Comment: Where `redirect` `RewriteMap` defined and what is its definition?

Answer (score 0):

One of many possibilities how to allow just one redirection is to use internal cookies.

Before executing `RewriteRule` check your internal redirection cookie by

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*htredirect=1.*$ [NC]
```

and then modify the `RewriteRule` by adding flag `[CO=htredirect:1:%{HTTP_HOST}]`, so the redirection cookie is set, which prevents the execution of the same rule again.